# Como obtener el evento change de un layer en OL3 usando ol.control.LayerSwitcher

Tags: javascript, geolocalización, openlayers-3

Estoy usando Open Layers 3 con el plugin [ol.control.LayerSwitcher](https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-layerswitcher) y quería saber como puedo obtener cuando cambio un layer en el switcher. Estuve buscando mucho en internet y no encuentro una solución a esto.
La idea es cuando se haga el cambio o la selección de un layer usando el plugin ol.control.LayerSwitcher realice una acción como por ejemplo un alert.

Si alguien me podría dar una ayuda o una alternativa a esto. Si saben de otra alternativa que no use ol.control.LayerSwitcher y determine el evento change de un layer especifico, me gustaría saberlo.

Digamos que tengo tres layers en el switcher.

- Layer1
- Layer2
- Layer3.

Por defecto esta en Layer1. Si cambio o selecciono el Layer2 quisiera que ejecute un alert. Pero siempre que se seleccione el Layer2. Osea tendría que ser un evento.

Comment: No me queda claro a qué te refieres con un cambio de layer. La visibilidad?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo  Digamos que tengo tres layers en el switcher. Layer1, Layer2 y Layer3. Por defecto esta en Layer1. Si cambio o selecciono el Layer2 quisiera que ejecute un alert.

Comment: puedes usar el evento 'change:visible' de una capa: `Layer1.on('change:visible', function(){})` suponiendo que son `baseLayers` y por tanto si muestras una se cierran las demás.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo me funciona lo que me dijiste. Serias tan amable en responder la pregunta. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los objetos que heredan de la clase [`ol.layer.Base`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Base.html) emiten el evento 'change:visible' cuando cambia su visibilidad.

Aségurate como en los ejemplos del LayerSwitcher que las Layers tengan la propiedad `type : 'base'` para que esto funcione.

Utiliza algo así entonces:

```
[Layer1, Layer2, Layer3].forEach(function(l){
  l.on('change:visible', function(e){
    console.log(`Mi capa ${l.name} está visible ? ${l.getVisible()}`)
  }
})
```